# How to compare and match two tables that aren't the same?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables and want them to be combined via an ID. This is what I have right now:

[image: Date]

I want the ID values to match and become this:

[image]

I'm struggling finding a way to do this via sorting or formula. The only way I can think to do it is manually but the actual data I have is 4k lines long so doing it manually would be a huge pain.

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Comment: So use index() with match(). You have a key with the numbers matching emails to names. Or vlookup().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data starts in A1 then:

```
   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,C:D,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Entered in cell D2 and dragged down. And should be starting with B2.

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly how I was hoping!